# What is the proper way to embed conditional business logic in a Node.js REST service?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am a newbie to building a Node.js/MongoDB application.
I understand the basics of setting up a MongoDB collection for simple CRUD operations.

However, what I am still trying to figure out is the following scenario -

Lets assume we have a collection named - `Customer (CustomerId, CustomerName, CustomerLocation, CustomerRating)`

Now with basic REST service setup in the Node.js layer, if I would like to update the customer collection - then we would have the following setup:

`customerRouter.route('/api/customer').put()` -> will update all the customer records in the collection.

However, If there was another scenario where I have to **conditionally update** all customer records in collection where either the `CustomerLocation = 'US'` or `CustomerRating > 100`, then how do i setup such business conditions to be passed to MongoDB from Node.js to include the conditions before performing updates?

What I am failing to understand here is that resource to update remains the same, the number of records to update could be either 'All' or 'Conditional Update'.

How do I pass these conditions from the Node.js layer?

What is also more important to note here is that the conditional update would not always be static condition to hard-code. Condition parameters should be framed dynamically.

- List item

(eg1: Parameter A is "A" (or) parameter B is less than < 50)
(eg2: Parameter A in "A,B,C" (and) Parameter C is greater than 200)

I am looking to frame the conditions on the fly and pass them to MongoDB from Node.js.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would fall under the categories of filtering, sorting, field selection and paging.  In which case you wouldn't change the route, but would add a **query string** to the end of the route.

Get all the customers who live in the U.S. `{host}/api/customer?location=us`

Get all the customers who live in the U.S. and have customer rating above one hundred `{host}/api/customer?location=us&rating>100`

Now, inside the Node.js route handler, you would add the logic to handle the query string.

Hope this helps.